# Use VBA to Relocate Folders from Old SharePoint Site to New Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, vba

I'm currently tasked with relocation ~13,000 project folders from an old SharePoint site to our new site. Each folder will have contents, sub-folders, contents within those folders, etc.

I'm sure there's a way to accomplish an automated transfer of documents from one site to the other through the file explorer, but I'm failing to be able to make any connection in VBA to begin testing/troubleshooting. I'm also not crazy about tossing a 100% cry for help out there without presenting something I've been working on. However, I'm at a complete loss here.

Does anyone have an example chunk of code that would allow me to set a from path and to path to automate this process? It's also worth noting that I don't have access to the server side of our SharePoint sites...

I appreciate your help and time!

Comment: Are you able to get server-side access? With that much stuff it would probably be quickest to just do a Site Collection backup/restore. Or even if you could get someone who does have access to do it from the server?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't and getting an admin to do it is a super long shot. I can accept the fact that it'll take a while to complete and would probably do it in waves...I was just hoping that VBA might be available. It's not an easy fix and that's why I'm coming to the experts. :)

Comment: Well I've done moves in the past using the Open in Explorer view of each library just doing a copy paste and robocopy and both are dreadfully slow even though it's all on the same VM. We're talking an hour to transfer 30~ documents. You say you have ~13000 folders, is that all in one library or is it spread out?

Comment: It's spread across a few different libraries. I tried to save a library as a template, but that, as you can imagine, exceeded the size limit. And I had to breakdown and just do the old fashioned copy/paste. You'd like that Microsoft would develop a migration tool for sites and libraries...?!

Answer (score 0):

While this wasn't ideal and not for a lack of trying - I had to manually copy and paste the files from site1 to my desktop to site2. Again, I'm amazed Microsoft hasn't developed a solution for content migration...